# Xml no devuelve su contenido

Tags: c#, xml, asp

estoy intentando leer un Xml pero al abrir el documento es como si este estuviera vació ya que no me retorna valor alguno los elementos del archivo aparentemente no existen :

```
protected void archivo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (File.HasFile)
        {

            File.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Subidos/" + File.FileName));
            string direccion = Server.MapPath("~/Subidos/" + File.FileName).ToString();
            XDocument archivo = new XDocument();
            archivo = XDocument.Load(direccion,LoadOptions.None);
            XElement clientes = archivo.Element("elementoClientes");
            IEnumerable<XElement> listac = clientes.Descendants("clientes");
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('" + listac.Count() + "');</script>");
        }
    }
```

por el momento este es el código  pero al momento de obtener la lista de elementos cliente me retorna un null pointer exception  y  ya probe usando XMLnode y tampoco me retorna algo

```html
<elementoClientes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ipc2.com/erp/v1 ../../../JDeveloper/mywork/appSpaDemo/bpmSample/SOA/Schemas/ERP.xsd"
 xmlns="http://www.ipc2.com/erp/v1">
 <clientes>
 <NIT>323232</NIT>
 <nombre>Ana</nombre>
 <direccion>Cualquiera</direccion>
 <telefono>323131313</telefono>
 <personaContacto>Maria</personaContacto>
 <correoElectronico>correo1@gmail.com</correoElectronico>
 <limiteCredito>500</limiteCredito>
 <diasCredito>20</diasCredito>
 <categoria>
 <codigo>212211</codigo>    
 <abreviatura>AN2</abreviatura>
 <descripcion>Cuaquiera</descripcion>
 </categoria>
 </clientes>


</elementoClientes>
```

este es el xml que estoy utilizando lo adjunto como referencia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He creado una pequeña reproducción en mi ordenador y con el xml que has pasado si que me devuelve valores:

```
XmlDocument archivo = new XmlDocument();
archivo.Load("file.xml");
foreach(XmlNode node in archivo.DocumentElement.ChildNodes)
{
    Console.Write(node.InnerText + " ");
};
```

Este es el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando la libreria Xml, puedes recorrer facilmente los ficheros xml. Dentro del foreach por cada XmlNode, puedes volver a recorrer los siguientes nodos si es necesario como en el caso de las categorias, necesitarias volver a recorrer con otro foreach.

Comment: Muchas Gracias me ha servido indagare más la librería